# How do I add gravatar/identicons into Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have looked at the following, but they aren't clear, particularly the reference to DataMapper and gem dependencies.

All I want as an outcome is to be able to take my @user.email value that is in a |do| loop and display a gravatar where the identicon is set to "y" -- in other words, those cute seemingly random drawings!

But when I look at what is available, it isn't clear what to do -- particularly the references to DataMapper and gem dependencies.

http://github.com/chrislloyd/gravtastic/tree/master

I am playing around with this, but I wanted to get feedback from others before diving too deep!

http://www.thechrisoshow.com/2008/10/27/adding-gravatars-to-your-rails-apps

I installed woods gravatar plugin:

http://github.com/woods/gravatar-plugin/tree/master which is the same as the one referred below...however, I get an error when I type in:

```
<%= gravatar_for @user %>
```

The error is:

```
undefined method `gravatar_for' for #<ActionView::Base:0x474ddf4>
```

Comment: Hi, I'm the author of Gravtastic. I've updated the library and made the README a little more clear. Ping me if you need any help using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a Gravatar Rails plugin that can be found here:

http://gravatarplugin.rubyforge.org/

Install the plugin like this:

```
  ruby script/plugin install svn://rubyforge.org//var/svn/gravatarplugin/plugins/gravatar
```

After installing the plugin, if your model responds to an 'email' method, this tag will show the Gravatar:

```
  <%= gravatar_for @user %>
```

Comment: Hi, I installed it and I get an error:

undefined method `gravatar_for' for #<ActionView::Base:0x47c08e0>

Comment: Is there something I am supposed to do to "enable" it?  I notice that it creates a plugin called gravatar-plugin...do I need to rename it?  I had to do that for restful_authentication.

Comment: ah...that did it!  How do I change the plugin so that the gravatar functions as an img_link?

Comment: probably wrap the link tag around the gravatar_for tag, so something like:
<%= link_to((gravatar_for @user), :controller => :your_controller, :action => :your_action %>

Comment: Cool!  Last quick queston: can I add d=identicon into the URL, and how?

Comment: I'd love to help you, but these questions are pretty mundane. Have you done any research on your own?

If you wanted to change the gravatar_url, you could look at the source code generating the gravatar img url (it's in vendor/plugins/gravatar).

If you wanted to change the actual link, you could look at the Rails documentation for link_to.

Comment: I did -- I didn't see an OPTION for gravatar_url in the actual helper.  Someone helped me, thanks.

Answer (score 13):

Put this code in your ApplicationHelper so that `gravatar_for` is available in all views.

```
def gravatar_for email, options = {}
    options = {:alt => 'avatar', :class => 'avatar', :size => 80}.merge! options
    id = Digest::MD5::hexdigest email.strip.downcase
    url = 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/' + id + '.jpg?s=' + options[:size].to_s
    options.delete :size
    image_tag url, options
end
```

In views:

```
<%= gravatar_for 'my@mail' %>
<%= gravatar_for 'my@mail', :size => 48 %>
<%= gravatar_for 'my@mail', :size => 32, :class => 'img-class', :alt => 'me' %>
```

I refined slant's solution. Following [Gravatar guidelines](http://gravatar.com/site/implement/images/), e-mails should be trimmed and lowercased before hashing. Also, it seems `require 'digest'` isn't needed (tested on Rails 3).

Comment: how do I set different types of gravatars (eg monsters)?

Comment: Append `&d=DEFAULT_ICON_NAME` to URL. I will modify my code on Monday when I am back at work. For icon names see http://gravatar.com/site/implement/images/

Answer (score 8):

Not to repeat too much, but instead to give a more detailed answer:

As Sam152 said, you must create an MD5 hash from the user's email address which is then used in a GET request to the gravatar server.

The easiest way to gain access to MD5 hashes is through Digest, part of the ActionPack (inside ActionView) gem. Place the following in 'config/environment.rb':

```
require 'digest'
```

Now you only need to use the following where you wish to display the user's gravatar:

```
image_tag("http://www.gravatar.com/avatar.php?gravatar_id=#{Digest::MD5::hexdigest(@user.email)}", :alt => 'Avatar', :class => 'avatar')
```

This requires no additional gems and you can create a helper as needed if all you require is pulling in the user's gravatar.

Answer (score 1):

You need to [MD5 hash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) the email address and then put it into a gravatar URL. That will give you the image URL. Below is an example of how to do it.

```
http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/  md5(email)  ?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG
```

If you want those random drawings that appear, you can use an MD5 hash to get them. You could hash the key value in a loop and obtain a list that way.

Comment: How do I add the d=identicon when I use the gravatar plugin?

Answer (score 1):

I use https://github.com/sinisterchipmunk/gravatar
it works well, I am only using the basics but it can do cashing and advanced options.

It is also simple to use:

```
Gravatar.new(email).image_url
```

for the identicons you could add wavatar as follows

```
Gravatar.new(email).image_url + '?d=wavatar'
```